# If you crack me once, I won't break

Tags: riddle

> If you crack me once, I won't break.
>
> You can continue once, twice... nine times!
>
> Then it's time for a break.
>
> What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are

> Knuckles (aka joints in your fingers)

Because

> Cracking your knuckles doesn't break (fracture) them. And you can continue 9 more times after the first, since there are 10 fingers (usually...), but then you need a break (interlude) before they can be cracked again

Comment: Yep, you got it! ^^

Comment: I disagree. I can crack my knuckles multiple times.

Comment: @pkr298 You mean you can crack a knuckle, then crack that same knuckle a few seconds later?

Comment: @riskymysteries Yes, I just keep doing it repeatedly without stopping. I'm a crack addict.

Comment: @pkr298 I'm... surprised.

Answer (score 3):

> A pack of alcoholic beverages?

> Or i guess a person drinking them. If you start getting drunk you think you can take more and more and be fine until you have an entire pack and pass out.

Comment: Lol! No, this is not the answer.

Comment: I love it. -"Can break 10 in a row then a break, what is it?" -"Beer!" -"Itt's green and go up and down.." -"Beer!"..

Comment: Won't work, you're already on a break if you're cracking open a cold one with the bois

Answer (score 3):

You are

> a password being bruteforced

Because

> One need to be very, *very* lucky to crack a password from the 1st attempt (or the password needs to be very weak). However, some APIs (protocols etc.) detect bruteforcing and after a certain number of attempts ("1, 2... 9 times") block further tries for a while ("it's time for a break").

Comment: Nice. But not the answer to this riddle.